# Difference in ssh/scp host resolving and network reachability

Tags: ssh, scp

I've got a virtual machine running on KVM on my localhost. I can ssh into it without problems using hostname (entered in /etc/hosts) or the IP address.

With:

```
scp root@remote:/somefile root@localvm:/
```

I get

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname localvm: Name or service not known
```

Using the IP address it says:

```
ssh: connect to host 192.168.122.132 port 22: Network is unreachable
```

This is interesting, I have no clue right now.

Edit: The localvm is not known on the remote host, this must be the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using synopsis `scp host1: host2:`, then the `scp` first connects to the first `host1` and then tries to connect to the `host2` from there (unfortunately not described in manual page). This means that the `host2` have to be resolvable from `host1` and also you need to be able to authenticate to this host from `host1`.

There is a note in manual page for `scp`:

> `-3`
>
> Copies between two remote hosts are transferred through the local host.  Without this option the data is copied directly between the two remote hosts.  Note that this option disables the progress meter.

This explains this behavior and how to workaround it: `scp -3 host1: host2:` will resolve both host from you local host and will work for you just fine.